# MATLAB 1-D Pseudo Wigner Distribution

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to implement the 1-D Pseudo Wigner Distribution. The distribution has this expression:

[image]

where n and k represent time and frequency, m is the shifting parameter. z[n] is a vector and z* is the complex conjugate. The author of this [article](http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/61694/1/Gabarda.pdf) say that

> it can be interpreted as the Discrete Fourier Transform of the product `z[n+m]z*[n-m]`.

I would like to know which is the smartest and fastest way to implement this (in particular the product `z[m+n]z*[n-m]`, if I get this then I can apply the `fft`) because I need to use this expression a lot of times. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: look here: http://eprints.qut.edu.au/2607/1/2607_1.pdf (section 4 onwards)

Comment: I read the article but I don't know very much about this field and I don't understand very well what they have done. However I have thought a bit about that and I reach this conclusion (in my case `z` is real not complex):
`z[m+n]z*[n-m] = {z[n]^2, z[n+1]z[n-1],z[n+2]z[n-2],...,z[n-1]z[n+1],..,}` thus what I have done is:
`w = fft(z.*fliplr(z));`
Could it be correct?